# Inspect.exe can find elements that UIAutomation cannot find

Tags: .net, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, inspect.exe

I have an application written in Qt/C++.  It has a Window with child windows ( LocalizedControlType: ‘window’).  Inspect can see these child windows, but my C# code using UIAutomation cannot.

Inspect can see these child windows even when in  "UI Automation" Mode.

Does Inspect use UIAutomation?

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496048/whats-the-difference-of-uispy-exe-and-inspect-exe-from-microsoft-windows-sdk)  suggests that the controls may be available using UIAutomationCore.dll but I can't see how to use that from .Net

UIAutomation cannot find the child Window using:

```
elementWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);
TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker 
TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker
TreeWalker.RawViewWalker
```

But the child window and its child elements are available in Inspect:

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
Name:   "Flight Info"
ControlType:    UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType:   "window"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:1591 t:227 r:1920 b:466}
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    false
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  7632
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:7632,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
IsPassword: false
HelpText:   ""
IsDialog:   false
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Flight Info"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: window (0x9)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    normal (0x0)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:   false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:   false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:  false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:  false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:   false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available:    false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:   false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
IsCustomNavigationPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPattern2Available:   false
FirstChild: "" 
LastChild:  "Float" button
Next:   "Reports" window
Previous:   "" 
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   "" 
    "Float" button
Ancestors:  "ACP RADAR" window
    "Desktop 1" pane
    [ No Parent ]
```

Comment: Yes, inspect uses UI automation (but the native API). You can also try this official program to check what it sees https://accessibilityinsights.io/ (inspect is kinda legacy with newer UIA constructs, although it still works fine). If you don't see the element, it means your code has issue in the way it searches (it can also be a timing issue, like with tooltip windows that only show during a period of time, etc these are notably difficult to catch with UIA). Try a Subtree scope FindAll from the root of your app, with a property condition on name ("Flight Info") for example.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I will try the SubTree scope.  If it does not work, is it possible to use the 'native API' you mentioned?  Is that UIAutomationCore.dll?  Is it possible to use this from C#.  If so isn't this a better approach anyway?

Comment: Using the SubTree scope and AutomationElement.NameProperty = "Flight Info" does not find the window, so I think I need to use the native API.

Comment: They are the same API, the .NET one is just a wrapper over the native one, but indeed the native one is up-to-date, so it's in general better however I'm not sure it will change anything to your problem. Just add a COM reference to windows\system32\UIAutomationCore.dll and the code is very similar (but not 100% compatible).

Comment: Thanks  @SimonMourier.  I took the code that you put into this thread: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77765554/how-to-use-findall-with-the-nuget-package-interop-uiautomationclient).  Are you the only person that understands this stuff! Is there decent documentation anywhere?  Anyway, it worked!  UIAutomationCore could get to the Flight Info window that .Net UIAutomation could not find.  Thankyou so much.  I have been working on this for, ehem, a week now.  Now I have a lot of code which uses UIAutomation which needs switching to Core.

Comment: There's documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 but it's not always easy to connect the dots and samples are scarce. You should answer yourself with your findings and possibly upvote what you found useful.